# 3-dots android menu on a phonegap app - trigger by native android controls

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I would like to create a native-like '3 dots' menu on my Android app, which I created with Phonegap.

I was looking for a css snippet, or some guidelines on how to implement the traditional '3 dots menu', preferably for bootstrap 3, but did not find anything.

Also, I would like to allow the user to trigger this menu using the native android controls, is it possible? how complicated should it be? (did not find any information via Google)

[Example from Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap provides a JavaScript event-based API for the phone's native functionality:

[**DOCS**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#menubutton)